# MySQL: Convert time string to milliseconds

Tags: mysql, time, type-conversion

I have a table in a MySQL database. In the table, I'm recording how long it takes to do several different steps in a test sequence. Each step gets its time recorded to a separate VARCHAR field.

I'd like to do some analysis on that data so I can look for anomalies in time required for each step.

Unfortunately, the time has gotten recorded in this format:

```
00:01:30.4538080
```

For analysis, I think I need the values to look like this instead:

```
90.4538080
```

Is there a way to safely update the database table to make that conversion?

Comment: If `01:30` corresponds to one hour, thirty minutes, then to what do the leading `00` values correspond?  Is that days, or something else?

Comment: `00:01:30.4538080` = 0 hours, 1 minute, 30 seconds, 453 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

I have to advise the next solution:

```
SET @time = '00:01:30.4538080';
SELECT 
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(@time, '%H:%i:%s.%f')) + SUBSTRING(@time, 9) Sec;
```

Result:

```
+===========+
| sec       |
+===========+
| 90.453808 |
+-----------+
```

[Run SQL query here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=388bef3ee48d0012d8dbf487f04163db&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)